# Vue.js: Duplicated CSS class(CSS Component) is defined when import the same css file

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I'm building an App with Vue.js and CSS Components. There are some Vue components, which share common styling.

Hello.vue:

```
<template>
  <div :class="$style.title">Hello, World</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {}
</script>
<style module src="./common.css"></style>
```

GoodBye.vue:

```
<template>
  <div :class="$style.title">Goodbye, cruel world.</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {}
</script>
<style module src="./common.css"></style>
```

common.css:

```
.title {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

When I compile and run this code, there are a duplicated CSS class(`._2miFMUAEBLdLB9wHpgrYF2`):

[Screenshot: Duplicated CSS classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYuoi.png)

How can I fix this duplication?

*Complete code is available here:* https://github.com/ryo-utsunomiya/css-modules-common-style

Comment: Just a guess: Include the CSS file in the pages that use the components, not inside the components themselves?

Comment: Thank you for giving suggestions. In fact, the scope of $style is component. We must somehow inject parent's $style into child components(like 
Bill Criswell's idea: `this.$commonStyles`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just digging into this last night! I'm still working on understanding the best approaches but I'll share what I've discovered so far.

What you have will output the same css twice in dev mode, but in production it is deduped thanks to this in the `webpack.prod.conf.js` file.

```
new OptimizeCSSPlugin({
  cssProcessorOptions: config.build.productionSourceMap
  ? { safe: true, map: { inline: false } }
  : { safe: true }
}),
```

However, this still adds duplicate hashes to your `app.js` to map the real class name to the module class name which can bloat up quick. This is true even if you name it.

The approach I'm leaning towards for now is just having a common stylesheet included in the root component with a simple non-scoped non-module style and the component will just have its own unique styles in it with `module`. You would just use the plain class names from common.

However, another approach I'm considering is doing this in my root component:

```
<style module="$commonStyles" src="./common.css"></style>
```

Then  making `this.$commonStyles` available throughout the app.

I'll let you know where I end up.

Comment: `OptimizeCSSPlugin` is what I wanted for. That's great!